# plt.show() not showing images

Tags: python, pytorch

My code is as follow:

```
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

import numpy
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


torch.set_printoptions(linewidth=120)

train_set = torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST(
    root='./data/FashionMNIST',
    train=True,
    download=True,
    transform=transforms.Compose([
        transforms.ToTensor()
    ])
) 

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    train_set, batch_size=10
)

sample = next(iter(train_set))
image, label = sample

plt.imshow(image.squeeze(), cmap='gray')
plt.show()
print(f"label:{label}")
```

I try to print an image via matploblib.pylot but nothing happens.

Plus, I'm doing this on my linux server, while the same code works quite well locally on my vscode.

Comment: You're on your linux server? Are you running this via a console, or on a jupyter notebook or via ssh or...?

Comment: vscode remote explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to viewing your *matplolib* window remotely, you can always save your plot as an image file and copy it to your local machine. This is as simple as using [`plt.savefig`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html)

```
plt.save(f'label:{label}.png')
```